# Prioritize UDP over FTP, SCP, etc. in Linux

Tags: linux, sockets, ftp, udp

I have a setup wherein one "master" Linux system communicates with 3 "slave" systems also running Linux on a dedicated Ethernet interface(just the master & the 3 slaves). The slaves send data to the master via UDP every 5 ms or so. In addition, the master has apps that continuously pull files from all 3 slaves via FTP, SCP, etc. protocols.

The UDP packets need to be collected by the master as fast as possible, preferably within 3-4 ms. 
When I run the setup with just the UDP reception app running on the master, I see that this condition is easily met. However, when the FTP/SCP/etc. apps are also left running, there are spikes in the reception time. The size of the files being transferred is pretty less but a new file is retrieved from each slave about every second or so.

The fact that the results are good when running the setup without the file transfer apps active tells that Linux network "queuing/scheduling" seems to be giving similar priority to both UDP & the other protocols. Maybe it's even holding off UDP if a FTP is going on?

Is there a way to tell Linux (programmatically/commands) to give highest priority to UDP communication & "pause" other things like file transfer when a UDP message is ready for reception?

Comment: distro/version of linux? There is renice and ionice if you issue lies around processing or io? hard to know where the bottleneck is

Comment: I'm using Linux 3.10. As I mentioned, if I don't run the FTP based apps, the UDP reception has minimal delay. The moment I do start them, I get spikes every now & then.
It doesn't seem as thought process priority is the issue. I've manually pushed the UDP reception app to a niceness value of -20. It seems as though Linux doesn't make FTP wait when a new UDP message comes through, i.e. the UDP message is handled only after the FTP transaction is completed.

Comment: try 'chrt -f -p [1..99] {pid}'

ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154867/real-time-processes-scheduling-in-linux

Comment: Just tried that & nope! Made no difference. I still get a lot of spikes in the delay. Even tried pushing the FTP app's priority down.
If I kill the FTP app, boom! Very minimal delays.

I'm wondering if socket priorities, the way Linux handled the queue bands & ToS values are more relevant here than process priorities.

Comment: If ionice, renice, scheduling don't help then there are 2 other options. Setting core affinity so only the process runs in a dedicated core or using tc to manage the packet scheduler in the kernel to place udp traffic first. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_traffic_control

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.